# CSS3 RotateY finish when unhover

Tags: html, css, rotation

Here come my code:

```
#body #body3 #big .item {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
}

#body #body3 #big .item:hover {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
```

The problem is when I hover on the item, it rotate but come back to original state instantly when I leave the mouse out. So how can I make them finish the 360 degree rotation even when I un-hover it ?

Comment: Seems fine on my Chrome...

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JGnhT/1/

Comment: Don't work for me, I guess...

Comment: @AzrielOmega http://jsfiddle.net/JGnhT/2/ What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Thanks you, it works great. I'm testing on FF and Chrome.

Comment: I get the real problem now. I'm using a square img and when I hover on it, feel like it not work smooth and the rotating animation is overwrite and overrun. Maybe I should try jQuerry solution instead of CSS3.

Comment: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ Better Jquery solution for rotating animation.